# How to check if there is a specific object and a specific number of said object in an array?

Tags: arrays, class, object, pygame, python-3.7

I have a game i'm making. Right now the game will need spawn a specific number of a specific type of enemy. For optimization's sake, I decided to fit it all into one list/array. While I am fully aware of how to check if said specific object is in an array, i'm not sure how to check how many of it there is. Game worked as intended before but that was before I tried putting it into one list.

I'm currently trying to do this using the "Inspect" module.
Ive already tried using for loops. i.e

```
for enemy in entities:
   if isinstance(enemy,Enemy)#"Enemy" is a class
   #do something worthwhile
```

The list

```
Entities = []
```

The piece of code controlling the spawning.

```
if len(entities) == 0:
        global enemypresent,enemyApresent,alienApresent
        enemypresent = 0
        enemyApresent = 0
        alienApresent = 0
        for enemy in entities:
            if isinstance(enemy,Enemy):
                enemypresent += 1
            if isinstance(enemy,EnemyAttack):
                enemyApresent += 1
            #if enemypresent < 5:
            #   entities.append(Enemy(random.randint(0,WIDTH-70),-50,70,70))
            if enemyApresent == 0:
                if random.randint(0,100) >= 75:
                    entities.append(AlienAttack(random.randint(0,WIDTH-70),-50,70,70))
                else:
                    entities.append(EnemyAttack(random.randint(0,WIDTH-70),-50,70,70))
```

I expect the code to check how many of a specific object there is in the list. i.e "There are 4 Regular enemies in entities list"
"There are 5 Attacking enemies in entities list" etc.

Any alternatives are also welcome.

Comment: you can create many lists - `entities`, `enemy_entities`, `enemyattack_entities` and then you can do `len(enemy_entities)` - but you will have to insert and remove items from all lists on your own. Or  you can use [pygame.sprite.Group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) and you can keep the same object in different groups,  ie. `all_group`, `enemy_group`, `enemyattack_group`, and then you can do `len(enemy_group)`. You will have to add items to groups manually but if you kill item then it will be remove from all groups automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the advice of @furas in his comment to make separate lists, or better separate `pygame.sprite.Group`s.

But if you want to keep them in a single list, you could count the different types in this way:

```
enemypresent = len([i for i in entities if type(i).__name__ == 'Enemy'])
enemyApresent = len([i for i in entities if type(i).__name__ == 'EnemyAttack'])
```

and so on for every "type" of enemy you have. Notice that I avoided to use `isinstance(i, Enemy)` and `isinstance(i, EnemyAttack)` because,quoting from the docs:

> `isinstance()` returns true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.

So if, for example, `EnemyAttack` were child of `Enemy`, the first line would count both, and that is not what you want I guess.

Another remark: in my solution you do not need a loop, but in general do not edit the list on which you are iterating. In your solution, you should keep the `if enemyApresent == 0:` block outside the loop.